# How the socket.io client can detect my node server port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using the socket.io for a simple chat script.
I created a simple server and that works without problems.
But I have a question about client side script and that mechanism !

For example I've this code on client file :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

So, How the " https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js " can detect my " server.js " file activated http port on this machine for sending requests and emits on my executed node server ?

This is just a client side script, how this can detect a server side script and find a server port ?
Or might be that just set a default port number on my script like as 3000 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It works pretty much standard.
Defaults are connecting to the same host/port where the webpage is being served.
Your webserver port info is available within the window scope, so there is no black magic here. Also, WS connections are bound to the `ws://` protocol.

If you want to change the default endpoint for your socket server, you can pass the string as parameter in the `io()` init

```
var endpoint = 'http://socket.myapp.com';
var socket = io(endpoint);
socket.on(...)
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you , so the socket io cant detect the reserved port with ws ( web socket ) protocol ?

Comment: I'm afraid it cannot, which is safer!

Comment: No, I did mean can :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you use this in socket.io code:

```
var socket = io();
```

That tells socket.io to look at `window.location.href` and connect to that host and that port (the same host and port that the web page came from).  socket.io has implemented it this way so that the current web page host and port can be the default place for socket.io to connect to.

If you write your node.js server to be both your web server that serves your web pages and to be your socket.io server, then this default works out very conveniently.  It also avoids CORs issues for the initial socket.io polling step which simplifies the socket.io server (because it's the same host and port as the web page which is not subject to CORs).

You don't have to use socket.io on the same host and port as the web server that the web page came from.  You can specify a URL such as:

```
var socket = io("http://somedomain.com:5000");
```

if you want to.

Comment: Thanks , But without the port number end of the url line that works and this issue was Interesting for me :-)

Comment: @Mohammad - Did this answer your question?  I can't tell what your comment means.